# How to load two scripts in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to load the RockTheVote embed signup on a react app. This is their embed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://register.rockthevote.com/assets/rtv-iframe.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  RtvIframe.init({
      partner: 1,
      source: "ovrpage"
    })
</script>
```

I have something like this right now but I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated in advance :)

```
const Register = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src =
      'https://register.rockthevote.com/assets/rtv-iframe.js';
    scriptTag.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(scriptTag);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="register">
      <script type="text/javascript">
  RtvIframe.init({
      partner: 1,
      source: "ovrpage"
    })
</script>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: What happens with your current code? `RtvIframe` won't be available until after mounting, so I suspect that causes an error.

Comment: RtvIframe causes an error there. Not sure how to embed that code in there?

Comment: Not sure if this is sufficient to solve your problem, but you should check if `RtvIframe` is defined and if the `init` method is available before trying to render the component. Something like: `return RtvIframe?.init && <div id="register">...`. Otherwise you are trying to call a method that doesn't exist. The `useEffect` hook will run once after the initial render, so you need to handle the case when the script hasn't been loaded yet.